# Django - Efficiently bulk create inherited models

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, inheritance, django-models, database-performance

**Python 2.7.9 Django 1.7 MySQL 5.6**

I would like to populate a whole bunch of object instances belonging to multiple classes, stack them up into a single `create()`-like query, open a database connection, execute the query, then close. My main motivation is performance, but code compactness is also a plus.

The functionality of `bulk_create()` appears to be exactly what I want, but I am in violation of at least one of the caveats listed [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create), i.e.

> It does not work with many-to-many relationships.

and

> It does not work with child models in a multi-table inheritance scenario.

These limitations are also described in [the source code](http://django.readthedocs.org/en/1.7.x/_modules/django/db/models/query.html) thus:

```
# So this case is fun. When you bulk insert you don't get the primary
# keys back (if it's an autoincrement), so you can't insert into the
# child tables which references this. There are two workarounds, 1)
# this could be implemented if you didn't have an autoincrement pk,
# and 2) you could do it by doing O(n) normal inserts into the parent
# tables to get the primary keys back, and then doing a single bulk
# insert into the childmost table. Some databases might allow doing
# this by using RETURNING clause for the insert query. We're punting
# on these for now because they are relatively rare cases.
```

But the error returned when I attempt it is the generic

> ValueError: Can't bulk create an inherited model

My models do not apparently contain any many-to-many fields or foreign keys. It is not entirely clear to me what multi-table inheritance scenarios they are referring to, so I'm not sure if that is my problem. I was hoping I could slip by with my structure that looks like this but then I got the general error, so no dice:

```
child class with OneToOneField---\
                                  \   
child class with OneToOneField----->---concrete parent class
                                  /
child class with OneToOneField---/
```

As far as the workarounds suggested in the source, #1 is not an option for me, and #2 does not look appealing because I assume it would entail sacrificing the gains in performance that I'm going for.

Are there other workarounds that could simulate `bulk_create()` while handling inheritance like this and not forgo the gains in performance? Do I need to go back down to raw SQL? I would not mind making a separate collection and executing a separate `INSERT`/`create()` for each child object type.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The workaround I settled on was wrapping all of my collected `create()`s in a [`with transaction.atomic():`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly). This greatly reduced running time by not opening any database connections or executing any queries until all of the Python had returned.

A downside could be that if any errors at all are encountered all changes are rolled back and the database is untouched. This could be remedied by chunking the `create()`s into batches and opening and closing a transaction around each one. (In my case this was not the desired behavior because I wanted all of the data or none of it.)